# Trying to create an x pattern with stars

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def x_pattern(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if (j == i) or (j == n-1-i):
                print('*', end='')
                i=i+1
                j=j-1
            else:
                print('', end='')
        print()
```

When I run this function it is not showing what I am trying to achieve.

```
x_pattern(5)
x_pattern(6)
x_pattern(7)
x_pattern(8)
```

Could anybody please point out what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Removed i = i+1 and j = j+1 as patrick suggested

Comment: Might help to show what your expected output for inputs of 5,6,7,8 are ...

Comment: You cannot modify the `i` and `j` in any way that influences whats  done on the next loops iteration ... as i and j are set to the next value when reaching the `for i in ... ` line

Comment: Thank you suggesting that. I removed that part and after that when running an even number through the function it shows two starts in each row and for odd numbers it shows two stars in all but the middle row. All without spaces.

Comment: You edited out the original code so now the question makes no sense... Also you should still change `print('')` to `print(' ')` in the `else` part

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry I've just put it back. I also was able to find the issue. I had to remove the modified i and j values for the inner for loop and I was also missing a "space" in the second print statement. The pattern now looks like an X pattern. Here's the link: https://imgur.com/I7caKeV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an even number, you probably only want to print one of the two middle rows:

```
def x_pattern(n):
    skip_middle = n%2 == 0 

    for i in range(n):
        if i == n/2 and skip_middle:  # skip one of the two middle lines of '...**...'
            continue
        for j in range(n): 
            if (j == i) or (j == n-1-i):
                print('*', end='') 
            else:
                print(' ', end='') # print a space here
        print()

for l in range(5,9): 
    x_pattern(l)
    print()
```

Output:

```
*   *
 * * 
  *  
 * * 
*   *

*    *
 *  * 
  **  
 *  * 
*    *

*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *   
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *

*      *
 *    * 
  *  *  
   **   
  *  *  
 *    * 
*      *
```

Problem here is that you get one row less then you specified - thats why I suggested adding the wanted output to your question.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I recently started learning python and was very hesitant to put this simple question here because I knew how it'd be received by the community. Really appreciate your help with this. Looks like I need to practice more on loops and my logics.